# Is there a way to authenticate users with Azure AD in web applications without relying on sessions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure-active-directory, jwt

I was tasked with adding an Azure AD authentication option to an older web application (it runs on .NET 4.7.2) that already authenticates users locally, but I can't figure how to exactly do this... Let me first explain how it authenticates users currently. It's fairly simple:

1. The user enters its user name and password in the login page;
2. The data is passed to an API endpoint which validates it against a database, creates a JWT security token with some claims and stores it as a cookie.

   ```
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("login")]
   [ResponseType(typeof(DataItemResponse<UserAuthViewModel>))]
   public IHttpActionResult Login([FromBody]AuthenticateViewModel request)
   {
       var user = _authenticate.Login(request);
       var token = _authenticate.CreateToken(request.Username, request.Password, request.UserDomainName, request.UserRemember);

       HttpCookie authCookie = _authenticate.CreateCookie(token, request.UserRemember);
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

       return Ok(new DataItemResponse<UserAuthViewModel>(new UserAuthViewModel(user)));
   }
   ```
3. All subsequent calls to protected API endpoints are validated by extracting the claims from the token cookie on the `System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync` method and validating them. Basically this:

   ```
    CookieHeaderValue cookie = request.Headers.GetCookies("Authorization").FirstOrDefault();
    string token = cookie["Authorization"].Value;
    var identity = JwtTokenHelper.ValidateToken(token);
    if (identity != null)
    {
        if (_authService.ValidateAuth(identity))
        {
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = identity;
            HttpContext.Current.User = identity;
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
   ```

It works on `<sessionState mode="Off"/>`.

Now some guys asked us to be able to login using their Azure AD accounts. We can't get rid of the current local authentication, of course, so I was hoping to put a "Login with Microsoft" option that would redirect to that Microsoft login page and then back to our application.

I was taking a look at some examples, like [this one](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet), but they all use the `Microsoft.Owin` lib which does not work on the `<sessionState mode="Off"/>` (as far as I figured). There's also [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation) which does things manually in a similar manner to the way it's done in our local authentication, but it's designed for desktop applications...

Comment: Can you share an example of the actual problems you encounter with session state off? I have experience with an asp.net application targeting 4.8 which does not use the session at all (sessionState mode = "Off") which authenticates with Azure AD. This is done with app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(...) being called during startup, referencing microsoft endpoints as the authority '"Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0"'.  UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication is in the Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect namespace so Owin doesn't directly depend on the session.

Comment: Following the example I mentioned, but disabling the session causes a ```NullReferenceException``` when the application is redirected back from Microsoft's login page, because ```httpContext.Session``` variable is null inside the ```AuthorizationCodeReceived``` delegate on ```AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp```. I'll take look at your suggestion now.

Comment: Is the error in relation to SessionTokenStore?

Comment: @JustAnotherDev I don't think so. I could track down the error to this ```AuthorizationCodeReceived``` delegate by inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/cd848ae478525fd4b7768e4fa6874ad275edf03c/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.OWIN/AppBuilderExtension.cs#L202). It tries to add some claims to the http session, which is disabled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested a simple example of this using the 4.7.2 framework. I set up OIDC authentication in like this:

**web.config:**

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientId" value="xxxxxxxx" />
    <add key="redirectUri" value="https://localhost:xxxxxx/" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  </system.web>
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0",
        RedirectUri = redirectUri,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
        Scope = "openid email profile offline_access User.Read",
        // ResponseType is set to request the code id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
        UseTokenLifetime = false,
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
        },
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider
        }
    }
);
}
```

OnAuthenticationFailed & OnRedirectToIdentityProvider don't contain references to session, they're just making sure scopes get set correctly and redirecting users to error pages as appropriate.

**Login Action Code:**

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

And that's enough to get this working with the session switched off.

*Alternatively:*

If you're absolutely tied to your current method you could try overriding the existing OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync and removing references to the session. My own implementation of this revolves around exchanging the code you get from the notification for an access token for use with MSGraph. Please note the example is ***separate*** from the method above. This is simplified example and is probably overkill for your situation:

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
{
    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync
}

private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
{    
    notification.HandleCodeRedemption();
    var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(OpenIDSettings.AppID)
            .WithRedirectUri(OpenIDSettings.RedirectUri)
            .WithClientSecret(OpenIDSettings.AppSecret)
            .Build();
     var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();
     notification.HandleCodeRedemption(null, result.IdToken);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @JustAnotherDev. Both your solutions worked well. Only in the "alternative" version I had to call ```.WithPkceCodeVerifier(codeVerifier)``` before the ```ExecuteAsync()```, the ```codeVerifier``` being obtained from the notification: ```notification.TokenEndpointRequest.Parameters.TryGetValue("code_verifier", out string codeVerifier)```. I also had to override the ```SecurityTokenValidated``` delegate, because the lib references the session in this delegate too. It actually uses the session to pass information between these delegates.

Comment: I'm pleased you've managed to get it working. I struggled for a while with a similar issue some time ago so I'm happy if I can save someone else from that pain!